# How can I organize data that I got from an HTML form to make a JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm a beginner programmer, and I need an idea of how to take the data that I get from an HTML form and put into a JSON file, but the code that I have made gives me a different mane for every object in my JSON file because a form can't have two inputs with the same name,it happens that in my form I use jQuery to append what is like "Question" and "Answer" Inputs, and the user can insert many question and they are all like question1, question2... and I would like it to be as an array of questions in the JSON file and not single objects (Don't know if it got clear)

what I have

```
{
"_method":"PUT",
"_token":"4EnPNxmaVmVdXnuYwxzLzWP06mMK7phHJMBJMt3v",
"2tipo":"discursiva",
"2enunciado":"teste pergunta discursiva",
"2resposta":"",
"3tipo":"objetiva",
"3enunciado":"teste pergunta objetiva",
"3alternativa2checkbox":"on",
"3alternativa2texto":"teste alternativa",
"3alternativa1checkbox":"on",
"3alternativa1texto":"teste alternativa"
}
```

How I want it to be:

```
{
"_method":"PUT",
"_token":"4EnPNxmaVmVdXnuYwxzLzWP06mMK7phHJMBJMt3v",
"question":[
    {
    "type":"discursiva",
    "quest":"teste pergunta discursiva",
    "ans":""
    },
    {
    "type":"objetiva",
    "quest":"teste pergunta objetiva",
    "ans":[
        {
        "alt":"on",
        "txt":"teste alternativa"
        }
        {
        "alt":"on",
        "txt":"teste alternativa"
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is my JS file:

```
    /**
     * Created by paulo on 11/10/15.
     */
        var cont = 1;

    //this is wrong I know
    var contAlt = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];



function createQuest(){
    if(document.getElementById('discursiva').checked) {

            var appd = $('<div class="q'+cont+'"><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="'+cont+'tipo" value="discursiva"><label>Questão '+cont+' -</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="'+cont+'enunciado"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="delQuest('+cont+')" >Remover pergunta</button><input type="hidden" name="'+cont+'resposta" value=""></div>');
            $(".quest").append(appd);
            cont++;

        }


        else if(document.getElementById('objetiva').checked) {

            var appd = $('<div class="q'+cont+'"><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="'+cont+'tipo" value="objetiva"><label>Questão '+cont+' -</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="'+cont+'enunciado"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="delQuest('+cont+')" >Remover pergunta</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addAlt('+cont+')" >Adicionar alternativa</button><div class="checkbox'+cont+'"><label><input type="checkbox" name="'+cont+'alternativa1checkbox"> Alternativa 1 </label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="'+cont+'alternativa1texto"></div></div>');
            $(".quest").append(appd);
            cont++;

        }


    }

    var del = 0;
    function delQuest(del) {

        var toDel = (".q" + del);
        $(toDel).remove();

    }


    function addAlt(add){

        contAlt[add]++;
        var appd = $('<div class="checkbox'+contAlt[add]+'"><label><input name="'+add+'alternativa'+contAlt[add]+'checkbox"type="checkbox"> Alternativa '+contAlt[add]+'</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="'+add+'alternativa'+contAlt[add]+'texto"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="delAlt('+contAlt[add]+')" >Remover alternativa</button></div>');
        var classe = (".checkbox"+add);
        $(classe).prepend(appd);

    }


    function delAlt(del){

        var toDel = (".checkbox" + del);
        $(toDel).remove();

    }
```

And this the php (I'm using laravel, btw):

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
    Criar novo sol
@stop
@section('script')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styleForm.css">
@stop

@section('div1')


{!! $id !!}



    {{--seleciona o tipo de questão--}}
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="discursiva" value="option1" checked>
            Discursiva
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="objetiva" value="option2">
            Objetiva
        </label>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="createQuest()" >Nova</button>


    {{--formulário aram--}}

    {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'new/'.$id, 'method' => 'PUT'))!!}

    <div class="quest">



    </div>
    {{--enviar--}}
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>  Salvar</button>
    </p>

    {!!Form::close()!!}


    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="../../js/indexForm.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/questionnaire.js"></script>

@stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery selectors will help you:

```
questions = [];
$(".quest > div[class^='q']").each(function(){
    var type = $(this).find("input[name$='tipo'").val();
    var quest = $(this).find("input[name$='enunciado'").val()
    var ans = [];
    $(this).find("div[class^='checkbox']").each(function(){
        var that = this;
        var check =  $(that).find("input[name$='checkbox']").val();
        var text = $(that).find("input[name$='texto']").val();
        ans.push({"alt": check, "txt": text});
    });

    questions.push({"type": type, "quest": quest, "ans": ans});

});
```

Comment: sorry but I'm not understanding where I supose to put this code :X

Comment: you need to create a questions object on form submit

Comment: the:
 oFormObject = document.forms['qid'];
    oFormObject.elements["questions"].value = JSON.stringify(questions);
returns a json in the form and when I transform my form into a json to save in the database with:
->update(['quest' => json_encode($input)]);
 it puts a \ in evey " of the first JSON.stringfy
can I fix that?

Comment: u can try to use oFormObject.elements["questions"].value = questions; and then make a json with the entire object or use stripslashes php funtion